# Dynamically modify id within html tag using embedded ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I dynamically set the id within an html tag?

Specifically, I'm trying to do the something like this:

```
<td <% "id=unit_" + unit.id.to_s %> > *content goes here*  </td>
```

where unit.id is an integer variable.

Can I used embedded ruby (i.e. <% %>) within an html tag like this?

If not, how else can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td id="<%= unit.id.to_s %>">...</td>
```

Comment: Thanks. that doesn't produce any errors, but the html generated is: <td id="" > It seems to ignore the embedded ruby

Comment: I apologise. You're spot on. I forgot the '=' in '<%='. thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

Anywhere in your template you place a `<% %>` or `<%= %>` tag it will be evaluated as ruby code. It's not like an html tag that can't be stuck inside other tags like `<li class=<p>>` or something. That's just nonsense. But with erb, that would be cool: `<td id="<%= unit.id %>">`

Notice the extension on the file names used with erb -  `my_view.html.erb`. This tells you the template is first processed by ERB (Embedded Ruby), aka ruby, and then it's read as an html document. So what you really care about is the document being valid html *after* it's processed by erb.

Hope that helps!

Also note that in your question you use the `<% %>` tag which will evaluate ruby but not output anything into your template. The `=` sign (`<%=`) tells erb to print out the result of the executed ruby code.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. that's really helpful... i'd give you an +1 if i had enough points!